# Is there a way to see details of search of a IndexSearcher

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I need to see details of why when I search the index using an IndexSearcher I get zero hits. Here is parts of my code:

```
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
ggstatic Set<Integer> toImport = new HashSet<Integer>();

ScoreDoc[] hits = searcher.search(query.query, indexSize).scoreDocs;
System.out.println(hits);
for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits){  
toImport.add(scoreDoc.doc);
}
....
for (Integer i : toImport) 
{
   System.out.println(indexReader.document(i).get("url"));
}
```

The "hits" is sometimes zero and sometimes other numbers but I want to see more details of why those queries match zero hits.

Here is a query and the docs which returns zero hits:

```
title:#billa content:#billa user:#billaindex
```

Three documents that do not match:

```
1) "helis_insta: #iceage #sit #billa #kuscheltier"
2) "paulii_danii: Mandala  \n#schmetterling #gewinnspiel #billa  #blühendesösterreich #malen #filzstifte"
3) "nora_hoeg: So. Jetzt amoi ehrlich: wer hat da von wem abgeschrieben?! #vienna #billa #merkur #wurst #saussage #bbq #summer #creative #graphicdesign #oiswurscht"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IndexSearcher](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html) class has a method called

> explain(Query query, int doc)

returning an Explanation that describes how doc scored against query.
The same can be achieved in Solr using the parameter:

> debug=true